# htmlParse fails to load external entity

Tags: xml, r

I'm trying to load some publicly available NHS data using R and the XML package but I keep getting the following error message:

> Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/bed-availability-and-occupancy/"

I can't seem to figure out what might be causing this despite looking through a few related question.

Here is my very simple code:

```
library("XML")
url <- "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/bed-availability-and-occupancy/"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
```

**Edit: Session Information**

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                            [5]
>   LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.0.1

Comment: It's not a valid XML document: [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.england.nhs.uk%2Fstatistics%2Fstatistical-work-areas%2Fbed-availability-and-occupancy%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1). It should at least be XHTML, HTML5 is not.

Comment: When I run the code on an Ubuntu box it succeeds, it also runs on r-fiddle.  Can you add sessionInfo() please?  http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=AfoyOSGm

Comment: sessionInfo() added! I suspect I have the answer already though. This is almost certainly being caused by my work's proxy. I've hit issues with this before (via QGIS) and have never found a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @Tumbledown, I had the same problem.  However after I rebooted my R session it worked again .... weird.

Answer (score 12):

Package XML has some issues. The problem is intermitent and has nothing to do with the URL. I solved the problem using the function GET of httr package in order to obtain the html code, then passed it to htmlParse, see below:

```
library("XML")
library(httr)
url <- "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/bed-availability-and-occupancy/"
doc <- htmlParse(rawToChar(GET(url)$content))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `rvest` & the `xml2` packages:

```
library(rvest) # github version
library(xml2)  # github version

url <- "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/bed-availability-and-occupancy/"
doc <- read_html(url)

doc %>% 
  html_nodes("a[href^='http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/bed-availability-and-occupancy/']") %>% 
  html_attr("href")

## [1] "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/bed-availability-and-occupancy/bed-data-overnight/"
## [2] "http://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/bed-availability-and-occupancy/bed-data-day-only/"
```

Comment: This 2nd set of commands returns a set of data where the previous one returned a value that could not be searched as easily.